# Post-processing captured video in AS3, creating slow motion

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4, html5-video

I have an interesting project wherein I need to allow users to capture video of themselves with a webcam at a kiosk, after which I email them a link to their video. The trick is the resulting video needs to be a 'slow motion' version of the captured video. So for example, if someone creates a 2 minute movie, the resulting movie will be 4 minutes.

I'd like to build this in Flex / AS3 if possible. I don't have issues capturing the video and storing it / generating and emailing a link, but slowing down the video is the real mind bender. I'm unsure how to approach 'batch post-processing' a set of videos using Adobe tools.

Has anyone had a project similar to this or have suggestions on routes to take in order to do this?

Thanks!
-Josh

Comment: Do you really need to post-process the videos ? Can't you simply play them back a different frame rate ?

Comment: I'm now investigating this. HTML 5 video supports this (see [this link](http://www.w3.org/2010/05/video/mediaevents.html)), but of course 45% of my site visitors are viewing in IE8, so I'm trying to create a Flash fallback. The issue with this is that Flash doesn't seem to be able to support dynamic playback with FLVs or MP4s.

Comment: I did find [this for Flash](http://www.flashcomguru.com/index.cfm/2005/8/2/slowmo). It's pretty old, and not super efficient, but for what I want to do, it seems like it will work alright. I'll keep working on it and update everyone. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is absolutely feasible from the client side, contrary to what some may believe. :)

http://code.google.com/p/flvrecorder/

Just adjust the capture rate, which shouldn't be too difficult all the source is there.

Alternatively, you could write an AIR app that launches Adobe Media Encoder after writing a file and launch it with a preset that has FTP info etc. Or you can just use the socket class to connect and upload over FTP.

http://code.google.com/p/fl-ftp/

Comment: Also Just read at the bottom of the FLVRecorder page he states that you cannot use the source for commercial use. However, you might be able to ignore this, since the license stated on the google code page is MIT license, meaning you can do whatever the hell you please. Once code is released and tagged as open source, that license cannot be retracted either.

Comment: This project is for a non-profit company, and it's an educational interactive...so I think I'm in the clear!

Answer (score 0):

It is not feasible to do this client-side.
Capture the video and send it to the server.
Use a library like FFMpeg to do your coneversions

Comment: If you are going to down vote give a reason why? There was nothing wrong with my answer.

Comment: Downvoted because with all due respect, everything is wrong with it. It is more than feasible to do this type of thing client-side as you can see from my accepted answer.