# How to slow down the Webcam reproduction

Tags: actionscript-3, video, webcam

What I need to do is easy: the purpose of this test is show down the speed of my webcam when the camera capture a white pixel so:

1/ I create a Camera

```
this.cam = Camera.getCamera();
this.velocidad = 24;  // I set up the fps in 24
this.cam.setMode(ancho,alto,velocidad);

vid = new Video(640,480);
vid.width = ancho;
vid.height = alto;
vid.attachCamera(cam);
addChild(vid);
```

2/ So now, when the pixel is recognized I need to change the current speed of the camera to 12 in order to slow down the user speed

I've tried with this code but the camera is frozen and nothing change.. I don't know if I have to delete the current instance of the camera and set up again with the disire fps

```
cam.setMode(640,480,12);
```

Answer (score 0):

See [`Camera.setMode()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Camera.html#setMode%28%29) to request a different frame rate, but note that what's available will depend on the camera.

Comment: I did this but nothing happens:


    _cam = Camera.getCamera();
   

   _vid = new Video();
   _vid.width = 640;
   _vid.height = 480;
   _vid.name = "WebCam";
   _vid.attachCamera(_cam);
   this.addChild(_vid);

   clickHandler(24);

    public function clickHandler(vel:Number):void
  {

   switch (vel)
   {
    case 12 :
     _cam.setMode(640, 480, 12);
     break;
    case 30 :
     _cam.setMode(640, 480, 20);
     break;
    case 24 :
     _cam.setMode(640, 480, 24);
     break;
   }

   removeChild(_vid);

  }



and when I need to change the fps, I did:

    clickHandler(10);

Comment: @m4g4bu Please, consider posting code or new info as edits to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not possible with just a config setting, property or method.

The possible solution would be to capture the cam and store its frames as bitmaps in and play (or render) them in sequence.

If this is not a commercial project, you can use this: http://code.google.com/p/flvrecorder/ to record and than load the video to play as you want.

**Edit:**
Here are some more links, since I can't code something for you now:

[Post-processing captured video in AS3, creating slow motion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5781951/post-processing-captured-video-in-as3-creating-slow-motion)
[playing slow motion, fast forward , rewind in a video player in flash video player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6261681/playing-slow-motion-fast-forward-rewind-in-a-video-player-in-flash-video-play)

Also, you can search Google for "as3 video slow" and it will give you more reference material and some examples.

Comment: I tried this but it's not working because basically the FLV is being reproduced when the webcam capture the white pixel so I need to slow down the current flv reproduction. I've tried to change the fps of the stage but nothing happens

Comment: I can't code something for you, but I've gave you the directions to follow. Here are some more links to help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6261681/playing-slow-motion-fast-forward-rewind-in-a-video-player-in-flash-video-play  and   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5781951/post-processing-captured-video-in-as3-creating-slow-motion